# Lot of SELECT and INSERTS in one script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I want to add a lot of lines in my mysql database. And for each of those lines I need to do a search in the database. I will describe how I am doing it right now, but there must be a better way for this.

In a while loop I loop trough an array in which I have the data for that I need to insert the values for value1, value2, value3.

Then I do a `SELECT id FROM table WHERE column='value3';`

And after that I `INSERT INTO insertTable VALUES (value1, value2, id);`

This method results in a lot of queries. A possible improvement could be to instead of queuing the inserts, put the insert values in a array again and create a multi insert at the end. But there are still a lot of SELECT queries.

Any clues how to improve this?

Comment: Could you combine the values and make one select

Comment: I'd really love to see some example code to be able to answer this.  Any chance that you can share the relevant portions?  Just click the `edit` button below the question (directly above these comments) to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way,

you could build a table to contain all your value1,value2,value3 values
like in a loop build up a statement that is similar to below:

first time through the loop make your sqlstatement to something like

```
CREATE TABLE T SELECT value1 as value1 ,value2 as value2,value3 as value3
```

Then everytime after that through the loop set your sqlstatement to append

```
UNION SELECT value1, value2, value3
```

Then execute that sql statement so that you have the table T with your values.

Then you can run a single INSERT like this.

```
INSERT INTO insertTable(value1,value2,id)
SELECT T.value1,T.value2,`table`.id
FROM T INNER JOIN `table` ON `table`.`column` = T.value3;
```

here's an sqlfiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58daf/1

then you can drop table T afterwards.

Or if you want, you can just build the SELECT UNION query without the create Table T and just put that query in brackets and put it after the `FROM` and Before the `T` directly in the INSERT statement and so you have one query.